# echo when certain value out of array equals your function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has this:

```
$autos[] = array(
        "auto" => "Audi A6",
        "Max snelheid" => "240 km/h",
        "Verbruik" => "1 op 12");

$autos[] = array(
        "auto" => "Porsche 911",
        "Max snelheid" => "290 km/h",
        "Verbruik" => "1 op 8");
```

and beneath I use a foreach that echo's this.

```
 foreach ($autos as $cars => $arr){
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($arr as $test => $data){
            echo '<td>'.$data.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
 }
```

How can I echo something when this value is `"Verbruik" => "1 op 11"`
If the 2nd number is higher then 11 I have to echo "That's Correct".

So example would be:

```
$autos[] = array(
    "auto" => "Fiat Panda",
    "Max snelheid" => "140 km/h",
    "Verbruik" => "1 op 11");
```

So when I would have that code above. How could I echo "That's correct" ?

Comment: just to make it clear, you want to echo only cars that have "Verbruik" => "1 op 11" ??

Comment: No I would like to echo my foreach, And when a value is 11 or bigger in the "verbruik" I would like to echo another "That's Correct".

Comment: Please if my answer was usefull to you, check it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode() function to explode your string "1 op 12" into array with 2 numbers, then check if the second number is bigger than 11 or whatever you want.

```
foreach ($autos as $cars => $arr){
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($arr as $test => $data){             
            echo '<td>'.$data." ";
            if($test == "Verbruik"){
              $temp = explode(" op ",$data);
              if($temp[1] > 11 ){
                  echo "correct "; // do whatever you want
              }  
            }
            echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
 }
```

Comment: This worked thanks! But let's say I have 3 arrays with value above 11. Then it says just correctcorrect. How can I put this next to $data? So it shows correct after data? In the correct <td> ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can move the if statement or display whatever you want inside the second foreach

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 foreach ($autos as $cars => $arr){
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($arr as $test => $data){
            $numbers = explode(" op ", $data);
            if($test == 'Verbruik'){

                if((int) $numbers[1] >= 11)

                     echo '<td>'.$data." , That's correct!</td>";
            }

            else
                echo '<td>'.$data.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
 }
```

Comment: Might be better to do something like `$a = explode(" ", $data)`. Then the last number could be retrieved with `$a[2]`...

Comment: Thanks for your input. The solution above is a better solution and I've used that 1.